# how to print for multiple files differently?

Tags: bash, tee

Give a single command line for searching a file ‘datafile’ for the string “Internet”, sending the output of the command to a file called ‘Internet.freq’ and any error message to a file ‘error.log’. Rewrite the command line so that both the output of the command and any error message go the a file called ‘outerrfile’

this is the question..the command i wrote is

```
grep "Internet" datafile >Internet.freq 2>error.log | tee outerrfile
```

but outerfile is always empty